# What does "made of" actually mean?

Tags: meaning

> The house is made of brick.
>
> The whooper is made of a beef patty.

The first is correct, but the second I am not sure, because when I hear "made of" I think "is mostly constituted of". We can say that a house is mostly constituted of bricks, but we can't say that a burger is mostly constituted of a beef patty. Is there any implication behind the phrasal verb "made of"?

Comment: I think you mean “Whopper”.   If you mean the famous fast-good hamburger, it is **also** made **using** bread, tomatoes, pickles, sauce, and other things, so **“made of a beef patty”** does not work.

Comment: For your information, you can also see/hear: The house is made of bricks or cement blocks. constitute is not a synonym of made of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say “X is made of Y”, Y is generally a raw material that you can put together to make an X. You can arrange a number of bricks together in a certain way to create a house. You cannot arrange “a beef patty” to make a Whopper. Perhaps you can say “The Whopper is made of beef patty” where “beef patty” (no article) is used as a mass noun. Though as @whiskeychief points out, the Whopper consists of other things as well like a bun and various toppings. I’d probably say “The Whopper is made *with* a beef patty” - where “with” indicates one of the components of the sandwich.

Also,  “The Whopper is made of beef” would be correct because “beef” is a mass noun and it would be understood that you’re talking about the meat part of the sandwich.

Comment: Exactly, you cannot arrange a beef patty to make a Whopper. Very clear.